# From static pages (with DWT) to broker database

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8, broker

Currently we have a 2013 SP1 environment where (.aspx) pages are published to the filesystem. The component templates use mostly Dream Weaver Templates.

Is is possible to publish this pages directly to the broker database (as-is) and serve them from a .NET MVC application with DD4t?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes, with a large **but**.

Your application needs to deal with:

- Fetching the page content from the database
- Storing it in the file system if your app server requires files to be present there (usually this is the case)
- Ensure the latest version is available on FS whenever a new version is published
- Remove the pages from FS if they are unpublished (probably easier to check for PageMeta on request, and if page is not available in DB, delete it from FS)